# Prove $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I want to make a combintronic proof for this. So far, I have we want to form a committee of *k* members with a president from *n* amount of people.

Thus on the left side we can select the *k* members from the *n* amount of people and then select a president from there.

How would I go about doing the Right side though?

Comment: The left side does NOT represent what you say.  If only gives selecting k members from n people.  There is no selecting of a president unless you multiply by k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the factorial definition of $\binom{n}{k}$, you get that
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!\cdot(n-k)!}=\frac{n\cdot (n-1)!}{k\cdot (k-1)!\cdot(n-k)!}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$$